# How to get height of a div tag if html is dynamically inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag on my page.

```
<div id="filterDropdowns"></div>
```

I made html markup in my javascript and then inserted into div.

```
var markup = "";
markup = //Here makup is created through some logic.
 $("#filterDropdowns").html(markup); //Inserted html
```

Everything is working fine.After this, when i trying to get the height of "filterdropdown", it's always 0. I have tried many ways to get the height but i am unable to get the height. I have tried jquery method like innerheight,outerHeight and javascript method as well but it always zero. How i can get the height?

Comment: what you mean by dynamic ..???

Comment: Which method is being used to get the height ?

Comment: You should show the specific code you tried. Maybe there's a syntax error or something else you're not catching.

Comment: I do not explicitly add html markup. I made in javascript.Then inseted in div tag

Comment: @KevBot there is no syntax error.

Comment: Show here the javascript you tried so far.

Comment: document.getElementById("filterDorwDowns").style.height and outerHeight both returns 0

Comment: Have you checked that 1) the markup is being injected and 2) the check for height happens **after** the markup is injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for get height via jQuery :

```
alert($("#filterDropdowns").find("div").height());
```

Comment: it returns inner div height when you have multiple div then use class .

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the height:

```
$("#filterDropdowns").height()
```

Simple as that. No matter how the content was inserted. Dynamically or not.
However, please consider the following:

1) Make sure you check the height of the element really after you had already inserted its content. If you check the height before adding the content then, well, an empty element's height is most likely 0 (unless it is styled somehow).

2) Make sure the element is visible at the time you are checking the height, otherwise the result of the height method might be at least inaccurate.

3) If the contents of the element is positioned absolutely or floating then the height of the element will actually remain 0.

Answer (score 1):

`height: auto;` wont work. The div created by your logic, add `height:inherit;` to that div and also give a constant height to you `#filterDropdowns` It needs a height. If parent is 0 the child cannot inherit the height. So either specify a height in your `div` created your logic or `inherit` the parents height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="filterDropdowns" style="height:auto"></div>
```

try this

Comment: @Nikunj your confused per minute ratio is way too high.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this solution

```
var currentHeight = 0;
$(window).load(function() {
    currentHeight = $('#filterDropdowns').outerHeight();
    console.log("set current height on load = " + currentHeight)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
html:

```
<div id="filterDropdowns" style="display:inline-block;height:auto"></div>
```

js:

```
$("#filterDropdowns").height()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery's `.attr()` function.

then, Write `$('#filterDropdowns').attr('height','yourvalue');`